# Install Pods via .podspec?

Tags: cocoapods

I found some iOS libraries in Github that has a `.podspec` file, but it does not appear in Cocoapods' repository. Is there any chance I can use `pod` commands to install this library?

Example library: [DDSlidingPanels](https://github.com/deem0n/DDSlidingPanels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can copy their podspec into another folder such as `~/.cocoapods/repos/whatever/name/version/name.podspec` and then CocoaPods will be able to find it.

Comment: 1 amendment: the path should be: `~/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/{LIBRARY_NAME}/{VERSION}/name.podspec`

Comment: No it shouldn't. If you do that it may interfere with updating the master repo. You should create your own private specs repo in the path I mentioned.